# Вывод данных в шаблоне Django

Tags: python, html, django

Не могу решить задачу вывода данных в шаблоне Django из списка состоящего из нескольких QuerySet.

Например получим несколько QuerySet, объединяем в список:
[<QuerySet [<Recipe: 111>, <Recipe: 222>]>, <QuerySet [<Recipe: 333>, <Recipe: 444>]>]

В интерфейсе необходимо вывести данные в следующем порядке:
Recipe: 111
Recipe: 333

Recipe 222
Recipe: 444

Т.е. из каждого QerySet брать элемент и выводить его. И так нужно пройтись по всем элементам. Все QuerySet гарантированно имеют одинаковое количество элементов.

Задачу пытаюсь решить через вложенные циклы **for**.

**views.py:**

```py
        days = []
        for i in range(n):
            days.append(int(i))
    
        response = render(request,
                          'recipes/generating_recipes.html',
                          {
                              'days': days,
                              'recipes': recipes,
                          },
                          )
        return response
```

*template.html:*

```py
    {% for j in days %}  
                {% for item in recipes %}
                     Название: {{ item.j.title }} 
                     Время приготовления: {{ item.j.cooking_time }} 
                     Способ приготовления: {{ item.j.text }}
                {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
```

Если в шаблоне изменить "j" на "0" (например, item.0.title), то код работает.

*models.py:*

```py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    """
    Модель рецепта
    """
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='recipes',
                               verbose_name='Автор публикации (пользователь)')
    title = models.CharField('Название рецепта', max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField('Картинка',
                              upload_to='grocery_assistant/recipes/img/')
    text = models.TextField('Текстовое описание')
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient,
                                         through='RecipeIngredient',
                                         verbose_name='Ингредиент')
    cooking_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Время приготовления')
    persons_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Количество персон', default=1)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',
                         allow_unicode=True,
                         unique=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag',
                                  related_name='recipes',
                                  verbose_name='Теги')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации', auto_now_add=True,
                                    db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pub_date',)
        verbose_name = 'рецепт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'рецепты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Прошу указать на ошибку или альтернативный способ решения. Спасибо.

Comment: пожалуйста дабавьте ваш model для recipe.

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow добавил

Comment: Зачем это нужно? Распишите подробнее